# Creating "bars" in website for unknown number of items

Tags: jquery, charts, progress-bar

I have no idea how to word this...

I am wondering the best way to be able to produce something similar to SO's "Reputation Chart"

[image: Rep Chart]

I am thinking of using this for a very simple "queue monitoring" mvc3 website.

e.g.
Using ajax, query my queues every x seconds to just get a simple count of the number of items int them.

Admin can then open the page and see the queue counts "real time".

Of course, I want this to be able to work if queues are added/deleted.  I'd actually have it horizontal and with a label, and perhaps even the count, but thats all gloss and make-up!

Is there a sensible way to acheive the graphical part?  The queue part is already working.

Initial thoughts are using jquery and an add-on...but not sure what to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Google Chart Image API - https://developers.google.com/chart/image/docs/data_formats

On online 'Wizard' - http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/

Basically, you simply add an 'img' element to your DOM and pass the appropriate parameters in the image URL. It will return you a ready to use image.

Here is an example of an image you might have generated for your use:
http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chxt=y&chbh=a&chs=300x225&cht=bvg&chco=A2C180&chd=t:10,50,60,80,40,60,30&chtt=Vertical+bar+chart

Comment: Thats brilliant (and never knew it existed!)  Only problem is that this site will have no external access :(  is there a jquery equivalent?

Comment: Hm, that's bad. Ok try some of these - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Comment: Lol...I was just reading that site... points to you for such quick answers

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery plugin [flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/).

If you combine a flot graph with AJAX and setTimeout, you can poll the server for new data as often as you want [link](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/ajax.html).

Comment: Upvoted as flot looks really good, but Hristo beat you to a "correct" answer with the info I gave.

Comment: no problem.  Yeah, flot is great and very easy to use.  I also love sparklines for quick, unobtrusive data vis (both of these are on the site linked to by Hristo - upvoted).